# Blank Windows 8 project with angular throws Module ngLocale is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, windows

I created a blank windows 8 store app, added [winstore-jscompat.js](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat/blob/master/winstore-jscompat.js) library for making AngularJS work in app. Then I added AngularJS library using Nugget package and also added Moment.js package too.

Now without making any change to application project and just by adding links to script if i run application it runs but in VS output window I get this error,

> 'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/2.0)'. 
>   Exception was thrown at line 1774, column 11 in
>   ms-appx://150a27ab-bab3-4ca8-9e0d-70c91e0d0349/scripts/angular.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale The
>   program '[2228] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Maybe this is something I could just ignore but it still bothers me, maybe it's because the way I am adding links to library ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App3</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular references -->
    <script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular-winjs.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_en-gb.js"></script>

    <!-- App3 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, did you ever get it sorted?

Comment: Getting the same issue. Appreciate if you could share the fix you found.